# What units are wait times in MySQL performance schema?

Tags: mysql

The documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-wait-summary-tables.html explains what the columns are, but does not mention the unit.

I assumed it may be microseconds, when I first noticed the numbers were in millions, but later I also see numbers in billions (`408,113,517,000`) in the `MIN_WAIT_TIME` column of my `performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest` table.

The documentation specifically says these columns are not aggregated and while I look at rows with one or two `COUNT_STAR` value, I am able to confirm this.

How do I read, and possibly try to optimise, `MIN_TIMER_WAIT`,`AVG_TIMER_WAIT`, and `MAX_TIMER_WAIT` columns?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you actually running? I found bug reports and fixes for extremely large `MIN_WAIT_TIME` values (e.g. https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/ab87e8547142d2014639b3f296f69e59a5f84a7c )

Comment: @Dai we are still on version 5.7

Comment: You *really* should update. Version 5.7 is ancient.

Comment: Probably nanoseconds.  See also "sys schema".

Comment: @RickJames what do you mean about seeing sys.schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit is picoseconds:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-events-waits-current-table.html

> ### `TIMER_START, TIMER_END, TIMER_WAIT`
>
> Timing information for the event. The unit for these values is picoseconds (trillionths of a second). The TIMER_START and TIMER_END values indicate when event timing started and ended. TIMER_WAIT is the event elapsed time (duration).
>
> If an event has not finished, TIMER_END is the current timer value and TIMER_WAIT is the time elapsed so far (TIMER_END − TIMER_START).
>
> If an event is produced from an instrument that has TIMED = NO, timing information is not collected, and TIMER_START, TIMER_END, and TIMER_WAIT are all NULL.